# Modal Form in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In Delphi 7, I have a model dialog and i would like to display inside the main form. Right now Its displaying outside the main window. 
Im new to Delphi and I was unable to find the answer.

I want to embed the modal form inside the main form.
When I coded Parent := Application.MainForm, the application runs and the form is loaded after that the application become struck in such a way that I cant do any anything.

Comment: What do you mean "inside the form" ?

Comment: Do you want embed this modal form in the main form or do you want create a MDI application?

Comment: I want to embed the modal form inside the main form. When I coded Parent := Application.MainForm, the application runs and the form is loaded after that the application become struck in such a way that I cant do any anything.

Comment: What would you expect to happen? A modal form is designed to stop everything else from happening until it is closed, and you've embedded it in your main form. This *stops* the code from your main form from executing until the modal form is closed.

Comment: Both modal form and main form are inactive. I want my modal form to be active and it must be displayed on my mainform. Now it is displaying in the screen instead of displaying in the fmainform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Position` property of the modal form to `poMainFormCenter`. Or specify `Left` and `Top` of the modal form to place it where you want to. A user still will be able to move the modal form.

AFAIK a control cannot be enabled if it is a child of a disabled window. So `Parent := Application.MainForm` will not do the trick: `ShowModal` explicitly disables all top-level windows before showing the modal form.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use "frames" for this.